# Get PFObject at index with swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a list (`self.stepsList`) with three `PFObject` in it (casted from `AnyObject`).

I can loop through and print their attributes such as order, steps, pace, id etc, which have been previously fetched from **Parse**. For example:

```
if let list = self.stepsList as? [PFObject] {

    for object in list {
        let steps = object["steps"] as! Int
        var stepsAsString = String(steps)
        println("You walked: \(stepsAsString)")
    }
}
```

I can however not find a solution to fetch an object at specific index from stepsList or list. How do I do that?

Comment: Actually, quite not understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to iterate the array or how to fetch objects from **Parse** based on index(where's index from Parse BTW)?

Comment: No fetching objects from Parse is quite easy to understand from their docs. Its after I have fetched the objects I have problems with I guess basic array stuff. My array has as I mentioned 3 objects. Each object is an intervall where you should either walk or run a certain amount of steps. 
Intervall 1 - 31 steps and the Bool for running is yes
Intervall 2 - 64 steps and running = no so you should walk 
Intervall 3 - 150 steps and running = yes so you should run
I want to fetch a certain intervall after a GUI action so I need to fetch 1, 2 or 3 depending on which intervall the user is at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can do this :

```
for index in 0..<list.count {
     let steps = list[index]["steps"] as! Int
     var stepsAsString = String(steps)
     println("You walked: \(stepsAsString)")
}
```

So you can get the object with an index like this

```
self.stepsList[0] as! PFObject
```

I don't know if this will help you

Ysee